# Layout won`t work at execution pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget, qlayout

In pyqt4 designer I created UI and set layouts here is my code generated by

```
pyuic4
```

in python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, 
_encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(354, 304)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.label_6 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_6"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label.setEnabled(True)
    self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
    self.line_nume = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
    self.line_nume.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("line_nume"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.line_nume)
    self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 1, 0, 1, 2)
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
    self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
    self.line_prenume = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
    self.line_prenume.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("line_prenume"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.line_prenume)
    self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 2, 0, 1, 2)
    self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.gridLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetMaximumSize)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
    self.F = QtGui.QRadioButton(Dialog)
    self.F.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("F"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.F, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    self.M = QtGui.QRadioButton(Dialog)
    self.M.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("M"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.M, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 3, 0, 1, 1)
    self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
    self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 3, 1, 2, 1)
    self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()


   self.horizontalLayout_3.
setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetMaximumSize)


self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_3"))
      self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4)
    self.spin = QtGui.QSpinBox(Dialog)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, 
QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
      sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)

  sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.spin.sizePolicy()
.hasHeightForWidth())
    self.spin.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.spin.setMinimum(13)
    self.spin.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("spin"))
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.spin)
    self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3, 4, 0, 1, 1)
    self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_4"))
    self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_5)
    self.line_mail = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
    self.line_mail.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("line_mail"))
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.line_mail)
    self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4, 5, 0, 1, 2)
    self.OK = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
    self.OK.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(85, 27))
    self.OK.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("OK"))
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.OK, 6, 1, 1, 1)

    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
    self.label_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Introduce-ti 
urmatoarele informatii:", None))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Nume      ", None))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Prenume", None))
    self.F.setText(_translate("Dialog", "F", None))
    self.M.setText(_translate("Dialog", "M", None))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Sex            ", 
None))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Varsta     ", None))
    self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Mail         ", None))
    self.OK.setText(_translate("Dialog", "OK", None))
```

`

and my main code :

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
#from PyQt4.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

from do import Ui_Dialog

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget) 
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(central_widget) 
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.OK.clicked.connect(lambda: self.handleButton)       
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_Dialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


    def handleButton(self):
        nume = ""
        prenume = ""
        mail = ""
        varsta  = ""

        nume = self.line_nume.text()
        prenume = self.line_prenume.text()
        mail = self.line_mail.text()
        varsta = self.spin.get()
        print(nume, prenume, mail)

    def initUi(self):
        nume = QtGui.QLabel('Nume')
        prenume = QtGui.QLabel('Prenume')
        review = QtGui.QLabel('Review')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`

at execution appears a window with button OK on top left and a lineEdit under button, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the 5 templates is used you must use the correct widget, in your case I think you have used the `Dialog without buttons` template, so the widget to use must be `QDialog`, not `QMainWindow`, you must also invoke the widget's constructor and call to the `setupUi()` method of the design:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

from do import Ui_Dialog

class MyApp(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.OK.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)


    def handleButton(self):
        nume = ""
        prenume = ""
        mail = ""
        varsta  = ""

        nume = self.line_nume.text()
        prenume = self.line_prenume.text()
        mail = self.line_mail.text()
        varsta = self.spin.value()
        print(nume, prenume, mail, varsta)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]